# HTTP header Get response with no content-length gives 502 bad gateway

Tags: http, http-headers

To create a comet connection (hanging get) i am not specifying the content-length in HTTP Header. This works on my system but will requested from another machine of institute LAN, it gives 502 Bad Gateway for the request.

If i mention content-length, i get the response but the connection gets closed, which i dont want. What can be the alternatives to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the HTTP/1.1 specification for connection persistence. Return `HTTP/1.1` in the reply. If the query was HTTP/1.1, default to keeping the connection open. If the query wasn't, default to closing it. If you get a `Connection: close` header, close the connection after sending the response. If you get a `Connection: keep-alive` header, keep the connection open even if that wasn't the protocol default.

If you don't want to follow `HTTP/1.1`, you can probably get connection persistence anyway. Just always include a `Connection: Keep-Alive` header if you successfully establish persistence through the rules above. Send a `Connection: Close` header if you cannot support a persistent connection even though the client requested one.

Basically, follow the [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html). If you know the content length, you should *always* send a `Content-Length` header. Use the persistence negotiation rules to establish a persistent connection if the client can support one.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried keeping Connection: Keep alive in header, but then too if Content-length isnt specified, it throws 502 bad gateway. Institute has proxy and firewall in between. But, i can't give content-length as connection closes after that. Any workarounds, please?

Comment: Are you sending 'HTTP/1.0' or 'HTTP/1.1' in your replies? Also, it's `Connection: Keep-Alive`.

Comment: I am sending back HTTP version as i get from client, should i keep it always 1.1? Yeah, i kept it Keep-alive. I got to know there is a proxy server which doesnt allow hanging get connection. What can be the ways to create persistent connection even on mentioning content-length in header.

Comment: You can send back as you get from the client. Just remember, if the client sends anything other than 1.1 (or greater), you default to closing the connection. If 1.1, default to keeping it open. If you send back anything other than 1.1, and the client requested the connection be kept alive, make sure to send a 'Connection: Keep-Alive' header. (If the client sent 1.1, keeping the connection alive is the default.)